# Can I change the priority of the css style in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a online css editor.If I change the css of an element using like `jQuery(selector).css()` or `element.style=""`,they all changed the inline style of an element. As you know, inline style has a higher priority than css style in external css files. How could I change the priority by javascript to let the added css style's priority equal to the style in css files?

Comment: You can't. You could instead have your editor build its own `<style>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!important` if you want your css style to be included anyhow whether its in external file or internal. If you want to implement inline css as well as external then:

```
 .styles { background: #ddd; padding:10px !important;}

 $("#yourDivId").addClass("styles");
```

Remember a single HTML tag can contain more than one class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass()` or `toggleClass()` (depending on what you're going for) to add a `class` instead:

```
$("element").addClass("classname2")
```

Then you put the class with more important css rules lower in the CSS hierarchy:

```
.classname1{
   //styles
}

.classname2{
  //higher priority styles
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/07vz119q/)

Answer (score 0):

As jmore009 mentioned, using classes is your only option. There is no way to make the styles in your external CSS file have equal importance to inline styles, you can only make them more important with the use of `!important`.

Either have the existing classes in your stylesheet ready to be added by the editor, or create them dynamically on the fly. e.g.

```
$('body').append('<style> .class{ style: value; } </style>');
```